# How to index multidimensional NumPy array using range?

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I always thought that `range(2)` and `:2` are identical when indexing an array. But that does not seem to be true for multidimensional arrays.

Assume `A = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])`.

`A[:2,:2]` correctly returns a `(2,2)` submatrix.

`A[range(2),range(2)]` does not do that, is returns two diagonal entries as a `(2,)` array. Why?

I understand that the diagonal entries are `A[range(2)[0], range(2)[0]]` and `A[range(2)[1], range(2)[1]]`, but why do I not get the `[0,1]` and `[1,0]` combinations?

Comment: They are two different things: `range(2)` is essentially equivalent to `[0,1,2]`, while `:2` is equivalent to `slice(2)`. `A[arr[0], arr[1]]` is looking up, while `A[slice0, slice1]` is slicing.

Comment: Oh, `slice`. I remember - that explains a lot!

Comment: When using `range` or lists or `np.array` for indexing, the arrays `broadcast` against each other.  With 2 1d array you get that diagonal, much as you would with `zip()`.  To get a block, at least one of those arrays has to be 2d, e.g. a column vector.  `np.ix_(range(2), range(3))` is a handy way of constructing arrays needed to return a block.  Play with it.  Read up on `advanced indexing`.